# Expected Value of Local Maxima and Local Minima

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations, random-variables

Recently I came across this question:

Given a random permutation of integers 1, 2, 3, …, n with a discrete, uniform distribution, find the expected number of local maxima. (A number is a local maxima if it is greater than the number before and after it.) For example, if n=4 and our permutation was 1, 4, 2, 3, then the # of local maxima would be 2 (both 4 and 3 are maxima).
I know the answer will be (n+1)/3 .I wanted to know what will be the answer when we have to consider the local maxima as well as the local minima i.e Finding out the expected number of local maxima and local minima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a numerical method that can be used to solve the problem for small K.

1) Brute force solve the problem for small x (say x = 3 to 12)
2) Find a common denominator for each of your solutions (for K = 2, the common denominator is 90)
3) put each solution in terms of the common denominator
4) Use the method of common differences to find what the maximum order of the quadratic equations will be $(ax^n + bx^{n-1} + cx^{n-2} ... )$
http://www.purplemath.com/modules/nextnumb.htm
5) using your solutions set up a matrix representing the system of linear equations and then solve the matrix, which will give you your values for $a, b, c$, ...
6) then use those values for your your equation.
7) simplify as desired

For $K = 2$, it simplifies to $E[X^2] = (40 X^2 - 144 X + 131)/90$
For $K = 3$, it simplifies to $E[X^3] = (280 X^3 -1344 X^2 + 2063 X - 1038)/945 $

Answer (score 9):

Let $n\ge 3$. Suppose that the permutation $\alpha$ takes $k$ to $a_k$ ($k=1$ to $n$). Let $\alpha'$ be the permutation that takes $k$ to $(n+1)-a_k$. Then the number of local maxima (minima) of $\alpha$ is the same as the number of local minima (maxima) of $\alpha'$. Thus by symmetry the expected number of local maxima and the expected number of local minima are the same.

If the expected number of local maxima is $\frac{n+1}{3}$, it follows that the expected number of points that are local maxima *or* local minima is $\frac{2(n+1)}{3}$.

For completeness, we give a proof that the expected number of local maxima is indeed $\frac{n+1}{3}$.

Your example shows that you are including **endpoint** maxima. The probability that a random permutation has a left  endpoint maximum is $\frac{1}{2}$, and the probability of a right endpoint maximum is the same, so the expected number of endpoint maxima is $1$.

Now let random variable $Y$ be the number of non-endpoint maxima. For $i=2$ to $n-1$, let $X_i=1$ if we have a local maximum at the $i$-th position, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then $Y=X_2+X_3+\cdots+X_{n-1}$, and therefore by the linearity of expectation
$$E(Y)=E(X_2)+E(X_3)+\cdots +E(X_{n-1}).$$
Now we find $\Pr(X_i=1)$. Consider the numbers that are in positions $i-1$, $i$, and $i+1$. There are $3!$ permutations of these numbers, and precisely $2$ of these permutations give a local maximum at $i$. Thus $\Pr(X_i=1)=\frac{2}{3!}=\frac{1}{3}$.

It follows that $E(Y)=(n-2)\cdot\frac{1}{3}$. Now add in the expected number $1$ of endpoint maxima.  We get $(n-2)\cdot\frac{1}{3}+1$, which simplifies to $\frac{n+1}{3}$.

**Remarks:** $1.$ We prove directly that the number of places at which we have a local max *or* min is $\frac{2(n+1)}{3}$.

An endpoint is always a local max or min, giving us $2$ points. For the others, if $2\le i\le n-1$, let $W_i=1$ if we have a local max or min at the $i$-th position, and $0$ otherwise. Then the number $Z$ of non-endpoint local max or min is $W_2+W_3+\cdots+W_{n-1}$.

The probability that $W_i=1$ is $\frac{4}{3!}=\frac{2}{3}$. Thus $E(Z)=(n-2)\cdot\frac{2}{3}$. Add $2$ for the endpoints.

$2.$ We used the method of *indicator* random variables. It is often far easier than finding the expectation of a random variable by first finding its distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Also can you tell me what will be the value of E(Y)^2 and E(Y)^3?

Comment: So you are looking only at non-endpoint local maxima. The same basic strategy works, bu it gets more complicated. We have $Y^2=(\sum_2^{n-1} X_i)^2$. Expand. We get terms $X_i^2$ and mixed terms $2X_iX_j$. The expectation of $X_i^2$ is easy, since $X_i^2=X_i$. The analysis of the expectation of $X_iX_j$ is more complicated. If $i$ and $j$ are neighbours, then $X_iX_j=0$. But not always. Much too long for a comment.

Comment: What will be the value for non adjacent Xi * Xj? If possible please add the calculations for Y^2 in the answer itself.

Comment: A separate question should really be asked. I will be largely away until tomorrow, but someone will likely answer. If I can find it when I am back, I will try to write out details.

Comment: wondering if X_i and X_{i+3} are independent or not.. X_i and X_{i+1} are clearly not.. As per my work-out even they are not.. any comments?

Comment: Yes, $X_i$ and $X_{i+3}$ are independent.

Comment: ok.. i actually considered a seq from X_{i-1} to X{i+y} where y = i+2, i+3, i+4, i+5.. so E(X_i X_{i+1}) should be zero as both cant dominate.. i got 1/15, 1/9 and 584/5040 for the other cases respectively.. so I thought they are not independent..