# What is the expected no. of local maxima in a circular permutation of $n$ numbers?

Tags: statistics, permutations, uniform-distribution

Given $n$ numbers. We permute these numbers uniformly at random and arrange them on circle. What is the expected number of local maxima?

**Note**: We call a local maximum a number that is greater than both of its neighbors.

This problem is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680660/expected-value-of-local-maxima-and-local-minima) except that here we are dealing with numbers arranged on the circle. Does $(n + 1)/3$ hold for this problem?

Comment: I would expect $n/3$ for the circle.  You lose the endpoint opportunities.  And in the case $n=5$ I get $n/3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is close.  The $+1$ comes from the endpoints, which are more likely to be maxima as they only have one neighbor.  The linked answer shows the chance for an interior point to be a local maximum is $\frac 13$, so by the linearity of expectation the expected total number is $\frac n3$.