# What is the expected number of local minima in an array with elements from a normal distribution

Tags: probability

If I draw samples from a normal distribution (assume any $\mu$ and $\sigma$) and arrange them in an array/list sequentially, what is the expected number of local minima in the array ??

This is some extension to the problem here ([Expected Value of Local Maxima and Local Minima](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680660/expected-value-of-local-maxima-and-local-minima)) but in place of a uniform, we have a **normal/Gaussian** distribution. Would it make any difference if we have a different kind of distribution?

Local minima is defined as if the number at $i$th position is less that its neighbours ( $(i-1)$th and $(i+1)$th elements) where they exist.

It did a simple simulation in python for large $n$ to get the fraction around $\frac{n+1}{3n}$ but I don't know how to prove it

Comment: the answer in the other question applies.  the key is that among any $3$ consecutive values, the middle one has $1/3$ chance to be the smallest.  this is true for Gaussian because, as a continuous random variable, the chance that any two values are equal is zero.  the actual r.v. can be some other continuous r.v. like exponential, etc.  (OTOH this method needs modification if e.g. you are rolling a die $n$ times, because in that case neighboring values can be equal.  would you like to solve that case as well as as exercise?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use indicator variables.  Let $X_i$ be the indicator variable for the $i^{th}$ slot (so $X_i=1$ if the $i^{th}$ entry is a local minimum and $=0$ otherwise).  I'll assume that you call either of the two endpoints a local minimum if it exceeds its single neighbor.  If you meant something else, it will be easy to modify the argument below.

Then $$E=\sum E[X_i]=2E[X_1]+\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}E[X_i]$$

For $1<i<n$ we see that $E[X_i]=\frac 13$ (one of the three is minimal, and it is equally likely to be any of the three).  Of course $E[X_1]=E[X_n]=\frac 12$

Thus the answer is $$\boxed {E=1+\frac {n-2}{3}=\frac {n+1}3}$$

Note: Trusting that (as @leonbloy suggests in the comments below) your simulation was computing the proportion of expected minima, this result clearly matches.

Edit: Yeah, I did mean proportion of the expected minima in my simulation.

Comment: The OP  says "...to get the fraction around  $\frac{n+1}{3n}$ ..." so I guess it means the _relative_ number of local minima (that is, divided by the total number of values).

Comment: @leonbloy  oh, perhaps you are correct.  Of course, elsewhere in the post the OP requests the expected number.  To be sure, if you divide my answer by $n$ you match the simulated data.

Comment: @PeacefulSoul  Thanks for spotting (and correcting) the typo!